# K-Means Clustering Performance Benchmarking

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have data that is 157-dimensional with 688 data-points. With the data I would like to perform clustering.

Since K-Means is the simplest algorithm, I have decided to begin with this method.

Here is the Sklearn function call:

`KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=4, n_init=10), name="k-means++", data=sales)`

Here are some output metrics:

```
init                  time    inertia   homo   compl  v-meas     ARI     AMI  num_clusters
k-means++             0.06s    38967   0.262   0.816   0.397   0.297   0.250      4
k-means++             0.05s    29825   0.321   0.847   0.466   0.338   0.306      6
k-means++             0.07s    23131   0.411   0.836   0.551   0.430   0.393      8
k-means++             0.09s    20566   0.636   0.817   0.715   0.788   0.621     10
k-means++             0.09s    18695   0.534   0.794   0.638   0.568   0.513     12
k-means++             0.11s    16805   0.773   0.852   0.810   0.916   0.760     14
k-means++             0.11s    15297   0.822   0.775   0.798   0.811   0.761     16
```

Can someone, please, help me interpret them?

I know that it is good to have a low `inertia` and high `homogeneity` score, but I do not know what a good threshold for these is.

For example, 15297 is the lowest `inertia` I have received, but that happens when the K-clusters is set to 16. Is this good or bad?

### Available abbreviations:

`homo` = homogeneity score;

`compl` = completeness score;

`v_meas` = v-measure score;

`ARI` = adjusted Rand score;

`AMI` = adjusted mutual info.

Comment: You need to read the literature on all these measures. For example inertia will be 0 if you set k=688. But that won't be a good result, will it? But this question is too broad to be answered here, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

- The more centroids you have, the lower inertia you will get. 
  Having more centroids (`num_clusters = centroids`) means more ways for inputs to be classified to a center, lowering the magnitude of inertia overall in a multi-dimensional space. However, having more centroids also means that it may be more complicated for a machine to reach convergence for a defined number of `max_iter` in each `n_init` (by default, `max_iter` is set to 300). So, you should understand that for each random initialisation of centroids (each start of `n_init`), your machine computes **KMeans** algorithm at maximum 300 times, trying to reach a state, where no reclassification of inputs is possible. Of course, if it reaches convergence earlier, then it proceeds to the next `n_init`. Equally, if your machine does not find a solution for a defined number of iterations (300 in your case), then it still does a next step with another random placement of centroids. After 10 initialisations, the best output in terms of inertia is taken. *You may try to increase both `max_iter` and `num_clusters` to see that it takes longer to find a solution.*
- There are no universal thresholds for `homo` and `inertia` due to the fact that there are different datasets. The amount of centroids should be chosen empirically, judging from the structure of data and the amount of clusters these inputs should have.
- `compl` is the completeness metrics that reaches its upper bound (1.0) if all inputs of a given class are assigned to the same cluster. Given that its interval is [0.0, 1.0], you may interpret it as a proportion. `homo` is the homogeneity metrics which interval is equal to `compl`. It reaches 1.0 if each cluster contains inputs of a single class. `v_meas` is simply a harmonic mean of those two metrics.
- `ARI` is actually the adjusted Rand score. You can read more about [ARI](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#adjusted-rand-index) and [AMI](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mutual-information-based-scores).

More general information about completeness score and homogeneity measure is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#homogeneity-completeness-and-v-measure).

---

Also, you should consider reducing the dimension size with [PCA](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd-oHF8PHUAhXGFJoKHdNxCs4QFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscikit-learn.org%2Fstable%2Fmodules%2Fgenerated%2Fsklearn.decomposition.PCA.html&usg=AFQjCNFFt0uiCgwNRmZTn8hxd5bjzukEOw), because performing **KMeans** on largely multi-dimensional data may give less satisfying results.